# Spotify Dockerfile Maven AWS ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, spotify

Has any one had luck in pushing a docker image to AWS ECR? If so pleas share the instructions.

Thanks
Matt

Answer (score 1):

Yes the process may seem a bit tricky at first. Here is briefly what you may want to do:

- make sure you've set up a [proper](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/repository-create.html) repo on ECR for your image.
- make your image tagged in AWS predefined format. Ie:

  `docker tag e9ae3c220b23 aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com/my-web-app`
- login to ECR. Ie:

  `eval $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region <your-region>)`
- and now you are ready to push the image:

  `docker push aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com/my-web-app`

The [complete guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/docker-push-ecr-image.html) may provide more details.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the reply. I was actually looking for using either a maven docker plugin like fabric8 or Spotify Docker Plugins to push the image to AWS ECR. Any ideas will be appreciated.